# What does the Quran or hadith say about a woman shouting at her husband?

Tags: hadith, women, reference-request, relationships, husband

Is there a Hadith or verse in the Holy Qur'an that says that a woman mustn't shout at her husband? I know this is not polite, but I would like to know if there's anything about this in the Holy Quran or Ahadeeth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "وعن أبي هريرة رضي الله عنه عن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم قال‏:‏ ‏"‏ لو
>   كنت آمرًا أحدًا أن يسجد لأحد لأمرت المرأة أن تسجد لزوجها‏"‏" (رواه
>   الترمذي وقال ‏:‏ حديث حسن صحيح‏)‏‏)‏‏.‏)
>
> Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: The Prophet
>   (PBUH) said, "If I were to order anyone to prostrate himself before
>   another, I would have ordered a woman to prostrate herself before her
>   husband".
>
> [At-Tirmidhi]

This hadeeth shows the importance of respect for the wife to her husband, including the shouting ...

I do not think there is clear evidence of the shouting in particular !!

Shouting during the talk is from  respected .. !!

Comment: This hadith appears illogical. Prophet would only command people (regardless of gender) to prostrate only in front of Allah , let far go of men and women.

Answer (score 2):

There is no Ayah nor Hadith directly answering this particular question AFAIK, although some scholars consider it "نشوز" (Nushooz / unobedience). There is a Hadith saying that the Prophet's wives would become angry with him sometimes, but I couldn't find out the form of their reactions.